# Programmatically insert data to word file and save in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have one asp.net application , and i want to insert header and some text to word file programmatically. then insert gridview data in same word file and then save here is code

```
protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Customers.doc"));
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();



}
```

now , gridview data is  inserting in that word doc file, but before gridview i want insert some text in to same file, 
 please help......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line

```
Response.Write("enter your text here");
```

before

```
GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanx.. it works... so can you tell me how can i add header like <h1></h1> in html, and how can i set that text in middle of the word doc page...???

Comment: I think you can use `Response.Write(@"<p><center>"+enter your text here+"</center></p>");`